# Авто растяжение контейнера с контентом

Tags: html, css, height, контейнеры

Здравствуйте Имеется данный код

```css
.container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflov: auto;
  min-height: 460px;
  width: 97%;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px grey;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  position: relative;
}

.block p {
  text-align: center;
}

#imgfirst {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#lasttext {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.img {
  height: 90px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

p {
  color: #028BBD;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="about">
  <div class="block"><img class="img" src="simpl.svg" id="imgfirst">
    <p>Text me when you are free to talk on the phone or in person and I am not sure if I can make it to the meeting tonight</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block"> <img class="img" src="redef.svg">
    <p>Text Text me when you are free to talk on the phone or in person and I am not sure if I can make it to the meeting tonight</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block"> <img class="img" src="speed.svg">
    <p id="lasttext">Text Text me when you are free to talk on the phone or in person and I am not sure if I can make it to the meeting tonight</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

При прописывании **min-height** либо **height:auto** контейнер почему то растягивается по вертикали вниз, далеко от контента, а не под его размер. Я не имею столь большого опыта в создании сайтов, поэтому подрорректируйте если где то есть косяк. спасибо

Comment: где растягивается? если у .block убрать min-height: 460px; , то вполне себе под контент

Comment: @Kjuri и то верно....

Comment: @Kjuri только что попробовал в мобильной версии. там все равно растягивается